# itextsharp remove field position

Tags: itext

I have this code to get field positions

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(ssPdf);

        var output = new MemoryStream();
        var stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, output);
IList<AcroFields.FieldPosition> positions =stamper.AcroFields.GetFieldPositions(ssName);
```

and this to remove one position rect

```
if (positions.count>0)
      positions.RemoveAt(1);
```

But then i dont have any method to set the field positions list to the stamper.
If i call the GetFieldPositions again it will return all the fields and not without the one i deleted

```
        IList<AcroFields.FieldPosition> positions2 = stamper.AcroFields.GetFieldPositions(ssName);
        stamper.Close();
        reader.Close();
```

Comment: There is more to a visualisation (widget) of a field than its mere position, but the entries of the list are not coupled with the widgets anymore. Thus, manipulating the list does not give rise to any changes at all. What is it you actually want to achieve? Do you want to remove a single widget? Or the whole field?

Comment: One single (widget)/position

Comment: If that widget can be described as "the widget of the field on page X", you can use `AcroFields.RemoveField(String name, int page)`. If it cannot be described that way, things get low level; in this case you can take the code of that method as template.